# Overlapping contents while data importing

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm doing a project using Excel VBA but, I have an issue while importing data. Each time I import data it overlaps existing column.

Can some one help me to resolve this issue, below is the code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim myFile As String, text As String, textline As String, Name As Integer, Phone As Integer, Address1 As Integer, Dated As Integer
Dim Email As Integer, Postcode As Integer, SR As Integer, MTM As Integer, Serial As Integer, Problem As Integer, Action As Integer


myFile = "C:\Users\test.txt"


Open myFile For Input As #1
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, textline
        text = text & textline
    Loop
Close #1

Name = InStr(text, "Name")
Phone = InStr(text, "Phone")
Address1 = InStr(text, "Address1")
Email = InStr(text, "Email")
Postcode = InStr(text, "Postcode")
SR = InStr(text, "SR")
MTM = InStr(text, "MTM")
Serial = InStr(text, "Serial")
Problem = InStr(text, "Problem")
Action = InStr(text, "Action")
Dated = InStr(text, "Dated")


Range("C11").Value = Mid(text, Name + 6, 15)
Range("H13").Value = Mid(text, Phone + 6, 8)
Range("C15").Value = Mid(text, Address1 + 9, 25)
Range("C13").Value = Mid(text, Email + 6, 15)
Range("H16").Value = Mid(text, Postcode + 9, 5)
Range("C10").Value = Mid(text, SR + 4, 8)
Range("H14").Value = Mid(text, MTM + 5, 8)
Range("H15").Value = Mid(text, Serial + 8, 9)
Range("C17").Value = Mid(text, Problem + 9, 15)
Range("C18").Value = Mid(text, Action + 7, 10)
Range("H10").Value = Mid(text, Dated + 7, 10)

End Sub
```

Find the data in attached sheet. The phone jumps to name column the same apply to other columns.Data in H13 is coming to C11 likewise others.

[image: DataSheet]

---

.

**Edit**

---

Hi Paul, I am still having issue with printing and converting the sheet to PDF.

Without using your first or second code.. I can run the below codes and into the sheet to PDF but now when after running ur first and second code, the below codes can't convert the sheet to PDF...I keep getting "application-defined or object-defined error" and Run-time error'1004' Document not saved. the document may be open, or an error may have encountered when saving..

May i know what is wrong with my code?

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim MyDate As String
    Dim report As String
    Dim Name As String

    FilePath = "C:\Users\Documents\test\"
    MyDate = Format(Date, " - MM-DD-YYYY")
    report = " - Quatation"
    Name = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C10")

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:I60").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        FileName:=FilePath & Name & MyDate & report
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub report()
    Dim myFile As String, lastRow As Long
    myFile = "C:\Users\Documents\test\" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C11") & "_" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C17") & Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".pdf"
    lastRow = Sheets("Sheet3").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1
    'Transfer data to sheet3
    Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(lastRow, 1) = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C11")
    Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(lastRow, 2) = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C17")
    Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(lastRow, 3) = Sheets("sheet1").Range("I28")
    Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(lastRow, 4) = Now
    Sheets("Sheet3").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(lastRow, 5), Address:=myFile, TextToDisplay:=myFile
    'Create invoice in PDF format
    Sheets("sheet1").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=myFile
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    'create invoice in XLSX format
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\Documents\test\" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C11") & "_" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C17") & "_" & Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51
    'ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

---

[image: Edit]

Comment: You have placed  insufficient information since your current code is part of the code you might be using. Also the attached sheet unable to explain what overlaps in the columns !! Please edit the code and upload complete look of the Sheet.

Comment: This is the entire code

Comment: I have put the entire code. As i said the code works but my issue is H13 data is cutting and some are coming to C11. the attached pics shows that "Phone" which supposed to be part of H13 cut and some are in c11..

Comment: @gist102 If you have a new question (which it looks like, since the original problem seemed to have been solved, you accepted an answer, you posted new code, and the additional question you now posed has nothing to do with overlapping), you must ask a new question. You can add a link to this post as it is related. You could also, as you have already done, post a comment on an answer to ping the user and bring the new question to their attention. This is how the Super User site works - one question per question. It is not a forum where you can ask follow-up questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make the code more efficient, maintainable, and a bit more dynamic

The two versions bellow determine the size of data based on location of next token (**`"Phone"`**)
relative to current token (**`"Name"`**)

---

.

**Version 1** uses arrays to map tokens to different cells on **`Sheet5`**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Const FULL_PATH = "C:\Users\test1.txt"

    Const TOKENS = "Name Phone Address1 Email Postcode SR MTM Serial Problem Action Dated"
    Const LOCATIONS = "C11 H13 C15 C13 H16 C10 H14 H15 C17 C18 H10"

    Dim fId As String, txt As String, txtLen As Long, idArr As Variant, locArr As Variant

    fId = FreeFile
    Open FULL_PATH For Input As fId
        txt = Input(LOF(fId), fId)  'Read entire file (not line-by-line)
    Close fId
    txtLen = Len(txt)

    idArr = Split(TOKENS)
    locArr = Split(LOCATIONS)

    Dim i As Long, k As String, sz As Long, found As Long, ub As Long

    ub = UBound(idArr)

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet5")     '<--- Update sheet name
        For i = LBound(idArr) To ub
            k = idArr(i)        'Name, Phone, etc
            found = InStr(txt, k) + Len(k) + 1  'Find current key in file
            If found > 0 Then   'Determine item length by finding the next key
                If i < ub Then sz = InStr(txt, idArr(i + 1)) Else sz = txtLen + 2
                .Range(locArr(i)).Value2 = Trim$(Mid$(txt, found, sz - found - 1))
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

---

.

**Version 2** uses a dictionary

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Const FULL_PATH = "C:\Users\test2.txt"
    Dim fId As String, txt As String, txtLen As Long, d As Object, dc As Long

    fId = FreeFile
    Open FULL_PATH For Input As fId
        txt = Input(LOF(fId), fId)  'Read entire file (not line-by-line)
    Close fId
    txtLen = Len(txt)
    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    d("Name") = "C11"   'Same as: d.Add Key:="Name", Item:="C11"
    d("Phone") = "H13"
    d("Address1") = "C15"
    d("Email") = "C13"
    d("Postcode") = "H16"
    d("SR") = "C10"
    d("MTM") = "H14"
    d("Serial") = "H15"
    d("Problem") = "C17"
    d("Action") = "C18"
    d("Dated") = "H10"
    dc = d.Count

    Dim i As Long, k As String, sz As Long, found As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet5")     '<--- Update sheet name
        For i = 0 To dc - 1     'd.Keys()(i) is a 0-based array
            k = d.Keys()(i)     'Name, Phone, etc
            found = InStr(txt, k) + Len(k) + 1  'Find the (first) key in file
            If found > 0 Then   'Determine item length by finding the next key
                If i < dc - 1 Then sz = InStr(txt, d.Keys()(i + 1)) Else sz = txtLen + 2
                .Range(d(k)).Value2 = Trim$(Mid$(txt, found, sz - found - 1))
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

---

.

**test1.txt**

```
Name Name1
Phone Phone1
Address1 Address11
Email Email1
Postcode Postcode1
SR SR1
MTM MTM1
Serial Serial1
Problem Problem1
Action Action1
Dated Dated1
```

**Result 1**:
[image: Result1]

.

**test2.txt**

```
Name Name2 Phone Phone2 Address1 Address12 Email Email2 Postcode Postcode2 SR SR2 MTM MTM2 Serial Serial2 Problem Problem2 Action Action2 Dated Dated2
```

**Result 2**:
[image: Result2]

---

Comment: Hi Paul, Each time i run the code i would get the following error " Run-time error '9': Subscript out of Range

Comment: Which line throws the error? (click the "Debug" button when it comes up). Also, make sure you **update the sheet name** on the line where you see this comment **`'<--- Update sheet name`**

Comment: Yea i did and it works.. Thanks for that assistance.. Really appreciate it.

Comment: I like your pattern of coding Paul.. Do you have a channel would love to learn more from u or perhaps get a tutor from u

Comment: If you look at my profile(s) you can go through the list of answers I provided here on SU, SO, and CodeReview. Feel free to ask any questions and notify me as well - I’ll respond as soon as I have some free time

Comment: Hi paul bica, I'm still facing more errors after adding your code. Kindly assist .. I have added the codes to my question

Comment: @gist - in the new code you posted make sure that all cells used to generate the filenames like `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C10")`, `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C11")`, and `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C17")` don't contain invalid characters (`\/:*?"<>|`). If you still have issues please create a new question - others may be able to help as well. If you do open a new question, also mention the line of code that generates the error, and the data contained in these cells (you can place breakpoints in the code and check the value for `FilePath` and the cells I mentioned)

Comment: The highlighted this on code 1   Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:I60").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    FileName:=FilePath & Name & MyDate & Report

Comment: @gist102 - I added an answer to your other question: [VBA error 1004 while exporting to PDF](https://superuser.com/questions/1330983/vba-error-1004-while-exporting-to-pdf), but the question marks are originating from your source file